# Why this _._1 shorthand isn't working?

Tags: scala

I am trying to flatten a map. Not sure why 1) is working but 2) isn't.

```
   scala> val m = Map(1->2, 2->4, 3->6)
    m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 6)
```

1)

```
scala> m.flatMap(e => List(e._1, e._2)
     | )
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6)
```

2)

```
 scala> m.flatMap(List(_._1,_._2))
    <console>:12: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1._1)
           m.flatMap(List(_._1,_._2))
                          ^
    <
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List(_._1, _._2)` is equivalent to `List(x => x._1, x => x._2)`. That is each expression using `_` is its own lambda and both lambdas are given as arguments to `List`.

There's no way to achieve what you want using a `_` shortcut, so you'll have to use option 1.

Comment: "so you'll have to use option 2' did you mean option 1?

Comment: @johnsam Yep, I did.

Comment: Or option 3: `m.flatMap{case (k,v) => List(k,v)}`